# A Guide to enrol for a PhD in Management with UK Regulated Qualifications

Tags: phd, united-states, application, canada

I want to enroll in a top Canadian/US university for PhD program in management with options in human resource management/entrepreneurship. I do not have a BSc degree but have over 14 years professional experience and completed the following British accredited qualifications:

- level 8 Qualifi diploma in strategic management and leadership;
- level 7 Qualifi diploma in executive management
- level 7 EBMA diploma in business administration
- level 7 Qualifi diploma in human resource management
- level 7 OTHM diploma in strategic leadership and management
- level 6 EBMA diploma in business administration.

According to the [UK framework for higher education qualifications](https://www.gov.uk/what-different-qualification-levels-mean/list-of-qualification-levels), levels 7 and 8 are equivalent to Masters and Doctorate respectively.

I want to be a practioner-scholar and an academic PhD is needed.

How do I go about the admission process? I have communicated with 2 recruiters who are 'unable' to guide.

Comment: I don't understand. If I read the link correctly, to be at level 8 you seem to already need a doctorate. Similar for 7 and a masters.

Comment: @Prof.Buffy .According to the aforementioned website and the UK Framework for Higher Education Qualifications FHEQ, it is seen as Professional/Industry doctorate. Speaking witha UK admission specialist, they don't allow 'direct' for PhD.

Comment: Don't bother with recruiters unaffiliated with universities. Talk directly with someone at a university of choice and ask them to evaluate your qualifications and give you advice. I think there is a language/terminology issue. I still don't understand the issue.

Comment: I can't answer this for lack of information, but if you have "the equivalent of" a doctorate then no one will question your lack of a bachelors for grad admissions. The problem will be that someone has to determine what "the equivalent of a doctorate" actually means. Graduate degrees in US/Canada are normally research degrees (with a few exceptions).

Comment: @Prof.Buffy..Thank you so much for the efforts.I did that already and was told it must be 'a research masters'. Spoke with the Awarding Body, told to approach the university directly. You can review the links below for more information: https://qualifi.net/qualifi-level-8-diploma-in-strategic-management-and-leadership/
 https://qualifi.net/university-progression/

Comment: Contact the admission teams of your target Universities and explain your specific situation. Your academic background is somewhat unusual (no BSc but many short professional courses), and deserve special consideration. General guidance may not apply well to your case.

Comment: @Dmitry Savostyanov....thank you for the advice.